LinkedList Java: Iterator is stuck at first node
The program will not iterate through the whole list of towns added. Gets stuck at index 1 of the linked list, which is in ascending order.
I have tried to move the cursor of the linked list by calling the previous() or the next() methods.
Below is the code made up of two classes.
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        var places = new LinkedList<PlacesToVisit>();

        addPlaces(places, new PlacesToVisit("Adelaide", 1374));
        addPlaces(places, new PlacesToVisit("Brisbane", 917));
        addPlaces(places, new PlacesToVisit("Perth", 3923));
        addPlaces(places, new PlacesToVisit("Alice Springs", 2771));
        addPlaces(places, new PlacesToVisit("Darwin", 3723));
        addPlaces(places, new PlacesToVisit("Melbourne", 877));

        addPlaces(places, new PlacesToVisit("Sydney", 0));

        System.out.println("First place to go is " + places.getFirst());





        boolean flag = true;

        while (flag) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            chooseOptions();
            switch (sc.next().toUpperCase().substring(0, 1)) {
                case "M" -> printMenu(places);
                case "F" -> moveForward(places);
                case "B" -> moveBack(places);
                case "L" -> System.out.println(places);
                case "Q" -> flag = false;
            }
        }



    }

    private static void chooseOptions() {

        String options = ("""
                Available actions (Select word or letter)
                (F)orward
                (B)acward
                (M)enu
                (L)ist places
                (Q)uit""");

        System.out.println(options + " ");
    }

    private static void printMenu(LinkedList<PlacesToVisit> list) {

        System.out.println(list);

    }

    private static void moveForward(LinkedList<PlacesToVisit> list) {

        var iterator = list.listIterator();

        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            iterator.next();

            if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(iterator.next());
            }
        }



    }

    private static void moveBack(LinkedList<PlacesToVisit> list) {

        var iterator = list.listIterator();

        if (iterator.hasPrevious()) {
            iterator.previous();

            if (iterator.hasPrevious()) {
                System.out.println(iterator.previous());
            }
        }


    }

    private static void addPlaces(LinkedList<PlacesToVisit> list, PlacesToVisit place) {

        if (list.contains(place)) {
            System.out.println("Found duplicate " + place);
            return;
        }

        for (PlacesToVisit p : list) {
            if (p.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(place.getName())) {
                System.out.println("Duplicate found" + place);
                return;
            }
        }

        int matchIndex = 0;
        for (var listPlace : list) {
            if (place.getDistance() < listPlace.getDistance()) {
                list.add(matchIndex, place);
                return;
            }

            matchIndex++;
        }

        list.add(place);
    }



}

public class PlacesToVisit {

    private String name;
    private int distance;

    public PlacesToVisit(String name, int distance) {
        this.name = name;
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s distance = %d", name, distance);
    }
}

When you run the program, the go forward and backwards methods do not execute. The backwards method does not execute at all.

list.listIterator() is not a variable, it’s an operation.  Every time you call that method, you get a brand new ListIterator which is pointing to the start of the List.

First, an aside. I would replace LinkedList with ArrayList because it's more efficient, and there are very few applications where LinkedList is better. You will find very few professionally written applications that use LinkedList. Also, use the interface List wherever possible.
An iterator of a list doesn't change anything about the list it's come from. Therefore, when you call list.listIterator() it returns a brand-new iterator pointing at the first element, not the last element that you had some previous iterator pointing at.
You should make your methods take an Iterator argument instead of a List.

tl;dr

Re-use rather than re-create your ListIterator.
Re-use rather than re-create your Scanner.

Details
As commented, the flaw in your code is re-creating, rather than re-using, the ListIterator object. Each call to list.listIterator() is creating a new iterator. This means you are losing the prior state of your moves forward & backward. Fix: Instantiate the ListIterator object only once, and hold a reference to it for repeated use.
Below is a revamp of your code, with a solution. Let's also cover some other issues in passing.
Your PlacesToVisit class represents a single place, so using a name in singular. Also, Place is sufficient, as being good or bad to visit is not represented within that class.
Tip: You can use an underscore in your numeric literals, for easier reading. So 1_374 rather than 1374.
If the main purpose of your Place class is to transparently communicate shallowly-immutable data, define the class as a record. The entire Place record can be a single line, as seen next.
public record Place( String name , int distance ) { }

We are not modifying the collection while iterating. So we can use an unmodifiable list rather than a modifiable LinkedList. The List.of methods are a handy way to generate an unmodifiable list.
List<Place> places = 
    List.of
    (
        new Place( "Adelaide", 1_374 ) ,
        new Place( "Brisbane", 917 ) ,
        new Place( "Perth", 3_923 ) ,
        new Place( "Alice Springs", 2_771 ) ,
        new Place( "Darwin", 3_723 ) ,
        new Place( "Melbourne", 877 ) ,
        new Place( "Sydney", 0 )
    );

Rather than put all your code in one place, try to separate out logically. So, for example, we can define a fetchPlaces subroutine.
private List < Place > fetchPlaces ( )
{
    List < Place > places =
            List.of
                    (
                            new Place( "Adelaide" , 1_374 ) ,
                            new Place( "Brisbane" , 917 ) ,
                            new Place( "Perth" , 3_923 ) ,
                            new Place( "Alice Springs" , 2_771 ) ,
                            new Place( "Darwin" , 3_723 ) ,
                            new Place( "Melbourne" , 877 ) ,
                            new Place( "Sydney" , 0 )
                    );
    return places;
}

Setting up this sample data should be done early on. The constructor of your app might be good place for that.
public App ( )
{
    List < Place > places = this.fetchPlaces( );
}

Now some code to run the console user-interface.
Your code:
        while (flag) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

… is re-creating the Scanner object unnecessarily. Set up once, and keep a reference handy.
I recommend using long descriptive names rather than abbreviations. Modern IDEs auto-create and auto-expand, so no extra typing involved. So Scanner scanner rather than Scanner sc.
Your subroutines for moveForward & moveBack seem too short to really be subroutines. So I kept the code local in my example below.
 The key point to see here: The runConsoleUserInterface method is passed a list of Place objects. That method immediately creates a list iterator object only one time on each call. The code further down in that method accesses that single iterator.
package work.basil.example.placestovisit;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App
{
    // Member fields
    private final List < Place > placesList;

    // Constructors
    public App ( )
    {
        this.placesList = this.fetchPlaces( );
    }

    private List < Place > fetchPlaces ( )
    {
        List < Place > places =
                List.of
                        (
                                new Place( "Adelaide" , 1_374 ) ,
                                new Place( "Brisbane" , 917 ) ,
                                new Place( "Perth" , 3_923 ) ,
                                new Place( "Alice Springs" , 2_771 ) ,
                                new Place( "Darwin" , 3_723 ) ,
                                new Place( "Melbourne" , 877 ) ,
                                new Place( "Sydney" , 0 )
                        );
        return places;
    }

    private void runConsoleUserInterface ( final List < Place > placesToVisit )
    {
        final List < Place > places = Objects.requireNonNull( placesToVisit );
        final ListIterator < Place > iterator = places.listIterator( );
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );

        boolean continueLoopingMenu = true;
        while ( continueLoopingMenu )
        {
            System.out.println( """
                                        
                    Available actions (Type one letter or word)
                    (F)orward
                    (B)acward
                    (L)ist places
                    (Q)uit
                                        
                    """
            );
            switch ( scanner.next( ).toUpperCase( ).substring( 0 , 1 ) )
            {
                case "F" ->
                {
                    if ( iterator.hasNext( ) )
                    {
                        String message = "# " + ( iterator.nextIndex( ) + 1 ) + " place: " + iterator.next( ).toString( );
                        System.out.println( message );
                    } else
                    {
                        System.out.println( "No more. You already saw the last item. " );
                    }
                }
                case "B" ->
                {
                    if ( iterator.hasPrevious( ) )
                    {
                        String message = "# " + ( iterator.previousIndex( ) + 1 ) + " place: " + iterator.previous( ).toString( );
                        System.out.println( message );
                    } else
                    {
                        System.out.println( "No more. You already saw the first item. " );
                    }
                }
                case "L" ->
                {
                    System.out.println( "All places:" );
                    places.forEach( System.out :: println );
                }
                case "Q" -> continueLoopingMenu = false;
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App( );
        app.runConsoleUserInterface( app.placesList );
        System.out.println( "INFO - End of `main`. " + Instant.now( ) );
    }
}

When run:
Available actions (Type one letter or word)
(F)orward
(B)acward
(L)ist places
(Q)uit


L
All places:
Place[name=Adelaide, distance=1374]
Place[name=Brisbane, distance=917]
Place[name=Perth, distance=3923]
Place[name=Alice Springs, distance=2771]
Place[name=Darwin, distance=3723]
Place[name=Melbourne, distance=877]
Place[name=Sydney, distance=0]

Available actions (Type one letter or word)
(F)orward
(B)acward
(L)ist places
(Q)uit


F
# 1 place: Place[name=Adelaide, distance=1374]

Available actions (Type one letter or word)
(F)orward
(B)acward
(L)ist places
(Q)uit


F
# 2 place: Place[name=Brisbane, distance=917]

Available actions (Type one letter or word)
(F)orward
(B)acward
(L)ist places
(Q)uit


F
# 3 place: Place[name=Perth, distance=3923]

Available actions (Type one letter or word)
(F)orward
(B)acward
(L)ist places
(Q)uit


F
# 4 place: Place[name=Alice Springs, distance=2771]

Available actions (Type one letter or word)
(F)orward
(B)acward
(L)ist places
(Q)uit


F
# 5 place: Place[name=Darwin, distance=3723]

Available actions (Type one letter or word)
(F)orward
(B)acward
(L)ist places
(Q)uit


F
# 6 place: Place[name=Melbourne, distance=877]

Available actions (Type one letter or word)
(F)orward
(B)acward
(L)ist places
(Q)uit


F
# 7 place: Place[name=Sydney, distance=0]

Available actions (Type one letter or word)
(F)orward
(B)acward
(L)ist places
(Q)uit


F
No more. You already saw the last item. 

Available actions (Type one letter or word)
(F)orward
(B)acward
(L)ist places
(Q)uit


B
# 7 place: Place[name=Sydney, distance=0]

Available actions (Type one letter or word)
(F)orward
(B)acward
(L)ist places
(Q)uit


B
# 6 place: Place[name=Melbourne, distance=877]

Available actions (Type one letter or word)
(F)orward
(B)acward
(L)ist places
(Q)uit


B
# 5 place: Place[name=Darwin, distance=3723]

Available actions (Type one letter or word)
(F)orward
(B)acward
(L)ist places
(Q)uit


B
# 4 place: Place[name=Alice Springs, distance=2771]

Available actions (Type one letter or word)
(F)orward
(B)acward
(L)ist places
(Q)uit


B
# 3 place: Place[name=Perth, distance=3923]

Available actions (Type one letter or word)
(F)orward
(B)acward
(L)ist places
(Q)uit


B
# 2 place: Place[name=Brisbane, distance=917]

Available actions (Type one letter or word)
(F)orward
(B)acward
(L)ist places
(Q)uit


B
# 1 place: Place[name=Adelaide, distance=1374]

Available actions (Type one letter or word)
(F)orward
(B)acward
(L)ist places
(Q)uit


B
No more. You already saw the first item. 

Available actions (Type one letter or word)
(F)orward
(B)acward
(L)ist places
(Q)uit


F
# 1 place: Place[name=Adelaide, distance=1374]

Available actions (Type one letter or word)
(F)orward
(B)acward
(L)ist places
(Q)uit

